# Add textboxes dynamically in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I work on an ASP.NET MVC project that I need some help with. I need to be able to create x number of textboxes when the user click "add textbox". When the user enter the page a viewmodel is loaded. This viewmodel need to handle the x number of textboxes that the user create when he is on the page so that when the page is posted these textboxes are part of the model. The model should look something like this..

```
public class PlanViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public List<EventViewModel> EventList { get; set; } // this should be the list of textboxes that the user "create" by clicking add new
}

public class EventViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I'm kinda lost on how to do this so any help is appreciated.

UPDATE

I've added this javascript that add textboxes client side..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
    return('<input type="text" name="events[0].Key" value="box1" /><input type="text" name="events[0].Value.StartDate" value="box2"/><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="RemoveTextBox(this)"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Remove</button>');
}
function AddTextBox() {
    var div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("");
    document.getElementById("divcontent").appendChild(div);
}
function RemoveTextBox(div) {
    document.getElementById("divcontent").removeChild(div.parentNode);
}
</script>

            <div id="divcontent" class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="AddTextBox()"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Add</button>
        </div>
```

I think I only need to add unique id's for the textboxes like this...

```
events[0].Key
events[1].Key
events[2].Key
```

and so on..

But I don't know how. Anyone knows?

Comment: Please have a look at [this blog](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)

Comment: Hi Martin, that should work. Now I need to generate the textboxes by javascript I guess..?

Comment: You need to generate the fields in Razor view, please see my answer.

Comment: You need to use JavaScript to make it work on client-side. Either you could post your form on server and then re-display form, adding additional field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Razor view:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.EventList.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.EventList[i].Name)
}
```

To set the name attribute of all edited elements in javascript, this is to be called on page load, and any time the collection changes (item is added or removed):

```
var children = document.getElementById("myDIV").children; // TODO: here supposing children are the input elements, may be different on your page (they may be nested in a different way)
for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
{
    var el = children[i];
    el.name = 'EventList[' + i + '].Name'; // TODO: look into source code of the generated page for the actual format of existing elements and then modify the mask accordingly
    el.id = 'EventList[' + i + '].Name';
}
```

Comment: Yes this works for the ones allready in the model, but the user need to be able to add x number of "extra" textboxes when on the page.

Comment: Ok, then you need to add the new one in javascript and set its name according to the syntax (using indexer variable i).

Comment: I've updated my post with the javascript I have right now that add textboxes, but I need to make the names unique, so if someone has an idea of that I appreciate it

Comment: After adding (or removing) the new item to DOM you could iterate in DOM over all the items and update their `name` attributes.

Comment: Hi Martin, could you maybe show me how to do that in javascript. I'm not that familiar with it to make that change....

Comment: Thanks a bunch Martin, cant try it right away but will tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a list of String, like this

`public String[] MyTextFields`

and then create HTML using Javascript, like this:

`<input name="myTextFields[0]"></input>`

`<input name="myTextFields[1]"></input>`

Answer (score 0):

If it is ok to have JS dependency than I suggest to use light Knockout library. It will help you to create/edit/delete your inputs. [Check example in JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yn9crg6w/).

Use HTML to adjust your view. Tag **data-bind** lets you to bind to data and events

```
<button data-bind="click: addInput">Add</button>
<div data-bind="foreach: inputs">
  <input data-bind="value: text"/><br />
</div>
<button data-bind="click: proceed">Proceed</button>
<!-- Use Knockout JS library -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Then small JS script which handles adding new input and processing data on click.

```
function InputData(text) {
  let self = this;
  self.text = text;
}
function InputViewModel() {
  let self = this;
  // Your array of HTML inputs
  self.inputs = ko.observableArray([new InputData("Default value")]);
  self.output = ko.observable();
  self.addInput = function() {
    // Dynamically adds new input on user click button "Add"
    self.inputs.push(new InputData(""));
  };
  self.proceed = function() {
    // Process all input with their values
    for (var i = 0; i < self.inputs().length; i++) {
        console.log(self.inputs()[i].text);
    }

  }
}
// Bind our JS to HTML view
ko.applyBindings(new InputViewModel());
```